# Shared Values for multiple modules in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I'm using drupal 7 to build a website. What annoys me the most that it seems there're so much fields which shares the same value across multiple modules setting. For example, E-mail address for site e-mail, simplenews sender and etc.

I'm wondering whether there's a way to solve the situation just like what we do in programming - using variable, so we don't need to change the values each by each, to keep them all the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set) & [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) drupal apis.

Example:
Set the value like this:

```
variable_set('email_id', 'abc@xyz.com');
```

Then you can retrieve it in any module like following:

```
$email_id = variable_get('email_id');
```

Comment: I'm wondering if we can use some modules to do that instead at api level?

Comment: I won't suggest to use module for that purpose. It is an unnecessary overhead. Still if needed, you can have a quick look here: https://drupal.org/project/variable